# How to create category programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I need to create more then 50+ category. I Tried manually it take a too much of time so how to create category programatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This one:

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
$parentId = '2';
 try{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setName('your cat name');
    $category->setUrlKey('your-cat-url-key');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    $category->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where i have to use this

Comment: copy code in a file and place it in your magento root dir and run from url like: www.yoursite.com/codefile.php

Comment: it's working fine

Comment: i'm getting error like "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Answer (score 0):

In  order  to fulfill,your requirement,***you can use php shell script***:

**Write php script at magento root dir.**

Using magento this you can  Create category quickly :

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("admin");
try{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setName('check');
    $category->setUrlKey('new-category');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT);
    $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    $category->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Or,you can use any 3-rd partly extension  like

[magentoworks](http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension/)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-categories-extension.html

or  follow below blog:

[sonassi](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quick-script-batch-create-magento-categories/)

Comment: Where i have to use this

Comment: i tried in your code to my root folder but it showing blank page

Comment: If it's showing a blank page it means the import was complete if you login to magento you should now see a category called `check`

Comment: No i checked it's not creating

Comment: after running the above script, im my admin i checked and a blank row got created without the name of the category

Answer (score 0):

For the bulk import categories you can use below extension.

http://www.magentoworks.net/magento-extension/

Or You can follow below link which provide script to import categories using CSV.

https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quick-script-batch-create-magento-categories/

Answer (score 0):

```
/* supply parent id */

$parentId = '10';

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->setName('Storybloks');
$category->setUrlKey('new-category');
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$category->setIsAnchor(0);

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());               

$category->save();
unset($category);
```